# WPF DataGrid not updating style after object in ObservableCollection is changed

Tags: c#, wpf

sorry for the mediocre title I wasn't sure the best way to word it. Basically I have an ObservableCollection of a class called ItemDisplay. ItemDisplay has a property called "State". I've setup the XAML to set the background of the rows in the DataGrid to change based on the value of the State property of each ItemDisplay. Here's the XAML:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="scheduledGrid" Margin="0,0,0.6,4.4" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionChanged="ScheduledGrid_SelectionChanged">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Selected">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Priced">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Failed">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

It works fine if the States of various items in the ObservableCollection are set before the ItemSource for the DataGrid is set, however I'd like the background for the rows to change as the State for the objects in the ObservableCollection changes. What I've been doing up until now was setting the ItemsSource to null, then setting it to the ObservableCollection again, which works I guess but definitely isn't the ideal solution.

Comment: We need the code for your viewmodel to troubleshoot this.  I suspect the items in your ObservableCollection are not firing property changes for State.

Comment: This may be an issue of the property not being notified of the change. Please share your viewmodel code

Comment: @FaseehHaris Refreshing the entire control is the wrong solution. The solution is as 17of26 says: The object *in* the collection needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and it needs to raise its PropertyChanged event when the value of one of its properties changes.

Comment: You could rely on the observablecollection if you set the instance of itemdisplay to itself. The observablecollection notifies insert removal or edit of an object at a time in it. But by far the more straightforward solution is implement inotifypropertychanged as suggested.